# Select statement with sum and multi-rows

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

```
select Document_id, Document_date, sum(document_money)
from documents
group by Docuemnt_id, Docuement_date;
```

The first query retrieves the following results:

```
1    01-FEB-2017      10000
2    02-FEB-2017      20000
3    03-FEB-2017      10000
```

Query #2:

```
select document_id, Document_date, document_money, document_details
from documents ;
```

Results:

```
1    01-FEB-2017      5000       rentment
1    01-FEB-2017      5000       food
2    02-FEB-2017      10000      car
2    02-FEB-2017      10000      house
3    03-FEB-2017      7000       mobiles
3    03-FEB-2017      3000       drinks
```

How can I create a query that gives me the document_no, the_date,
the sum of the money and the details as following:

```
 1    01-FEB-2017      10000      rentment
 1    01-FEB-2017      10000      food
 2    02-FEB-2017      20000      car
 2    02-FEB-2017      20000      house
 3    03-FEB-2017      10000      mobiles
 3    03-FEB-2017      10000      drinks
```

Comment: MySQL? Or Oracle? Or both (really?)  -  Whenever you post, take a look at the tabs StackOverflow attaches to your post, they are always wrong. Select the tags that truly apply to your question.

Comment: Please tag properly.  It's useless if we write answer for the wrong database.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. but as far as I know, the answer would be the same. anyways, it's for oracle database8i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **analytic** SUM() function:

```
select document_id, document_date, 
       sum(document_money) over (partition by document_id, document_date) as sum_money,
       document_details
from   documents;
```